# About : AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

In my project, I used `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` to play SystemSound.When test in iPhone5,it works.
when in the iPhone4,it can‘t work .
Thanks for your help:

### here is the code:

```
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

I have import AudioToolbox.AVFoundation.framework,#import

but it is no use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this are the two ways to make your device vibrate

```
1) AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
2) AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

also you need to import

```
 #import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Comment: I did what you say ,but it can't work.Oh,my god,This problem has troubled my life

Comment: It works,thanks a lot. Here is the answer: I wrote this method in the base class, and then call GameScene inside.I just try to put"AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);" in place GameScene class inside, build, then it is easy to use